# Angular - HTML5 input type "datetime-local" not working with Date Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I've tried in many ways.
First I get the date as Moment.js object,

```
 this.meeting.start = event.date.local().toDate();
```

I also tried the following:

```
this.meeting.start = new Date(this.meeting.start.toLocaleString());
```

my html:

```
<input 
  type="datetime-local" 
  class="form-control" 
  value="{{meeting.start}}" 
  [(ngModel)]="meeting.start" />
```

but the UI window is empty:"--:-- dd/mm/yy"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the help I got here, I managed to get this to work with this workaround:

```
var add = moment(this.meeting.start).add(3, 'hours');
var result = add.toISOString().split('.')[0];
this.meeting.start = result;
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me :

```
let today = new Date();
this.meeting.start = today.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

in html

```
<input 
  type="date" 
  class="form-control" 
  value="{{meeting.start}}" 
  [(ngModel)]="meeting.start" />
```

please see example in https://angular-rb5vmu.stackblitz.io (last item : Input Date Format )

Edited!

Comment: worked because I used type="date", this works with type="datetime-local" this.meeting.start = today.toISOString().split('.')[0];

Comment: Ok it is displaying in the UI window, but the wrong (probably UTC) time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const fmt = 'HH:mm DD/MM/YY';
const result = moment.utc(this.meeting.start, fmt).local().format(fmt);
```

Template:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [value]="result">
```

[**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufszmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Give me a sample `this.meeting.start`. It's giving me `Date: "06/09/2018 20:49:23"` for today's date, which is my local time. For you, you'll have to change the `fmt` to the one that I've updated in the answer.

Comment: Example: "Thu Sep 06 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0300". I also edited the post.
The format is working but <input> is still not showing anything

Comment: Its formatting "Thu Sep 06 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0300" to "06/09/2018 10:00:00" but  <input> has no value

Comment: I don't want input type to be text. it needs to be datetime-local

Comment: You've binded `[(ngModel)]` as well as `value`. When you should only be using one of them.

Comment: You're almost there; just the format has to be `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm` (and you don't need the format when calling `utc()`): https://angular-u9inhr.stackblitz.io.

Comment: @AaYy What browser are you using? It work on Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Oh, that link got screwed up and was using the same code as the answer. Try https://angular-1fsxgs.stackblitz.io. You can edit using [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fsxgs)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I tried all the answers above but none worked..

```js
// Init dates
let today = moment.utc().local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
let todayMinus7Days = moment.utc().local().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');

console.log(today);
console.log(todayMinus7Days);
```

And the result from the browser console is :

[image]

And the result is the browser itself is :

[image]